# when I open my index.html file by clicking on it and without lite-server none of the bootstrap classes works /node.js and react/

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs

So I'm noob in working with node.js and react but I started developing a simple website.
I have some questions but I don't have any programmers around me.
I use lite-server for browser syncing , but when I open my index.html file without that-I mean by only clicking on it and opening it in chrome- it looks like none of the bootstrap classes works. so if I want to open the project I developed in localhost in a different computer what should I do ? and why this happens??
cause I have developed simple websites like this one before-without node.js- and I could zip the whole root folder and send it to someone else but now it's not possible for me to do so.

Comment: edit the question and provide your `index.html` code to see what is wrong with it

Comment: I don't think something's wrong with my code . I actually don't understand the way node.js works. and I need someone explain it to me ! :)) I also want to know how to open my index.html file -which works just fine with lite server - in a different PC ...

Comment: the css tag is not needed at all here. please edit your tags according to the tech (languages/frameworks/libraries) that you are asking in the question. Please remove the unnecessary tags